# Shape of particle's motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, orbital-motion

Let's a particle  is moving in a  orbit with force field $\vec{F}(r)= -kr^2\hat{r}$ 
Is there any way to tell that what would be the shape of the path of the orbital motion? Circular? Parabolic?

Lets assume the path is circular type and I want to change the constant $k$ to $2k$ or $k$ to $k/2$. By changing the constant how will it affect the orbital path of the particle.

EDIT:

Do I have to find out the effective potential or the total energy of the particle to get the shape of  the orbit? In the text, it has been given that, the orbit is circular and if we  halve the constant k then we will get the orbit like parabolic.

Comment: You may be interested in Bertrand's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem. It's  a surprisingly general proof that the only central potentials that will cause closed orbits are the harmonic oscillator and the 1/r potential (Kepler problem). Except in special cases (for discrete values of angular momentum) all other forces will cause complex (often chaotic) orbits.

Comment: Upper division and graduate mechanics texts usually do this in detail. One of the special cases that @CuriousOne mentions is the circular orbit *including the center of force* for the $r^{-5}$ case.